# What does a `reference measure' mean in the context of defining Shannon entropy?

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

I have come across the following definition of Shannon entropy:

The Shannon entropy of a random variable $X$ with distribution $\mu$, with respect to a reference measure $\rho$ is $$H_\rho[X] := - \mathbb{E}_\mu[\log \frac{d\mu}{d\rho}]$$ when $\mu \ll \rho$.

What does a reference measure mean here? How does this compare to the discrete definition $H[X] = -\sum_{x} P[X = x] \log P[X = x]$?

Answer (score 4):

You mean $\mu\ll\rho$ (I made the correction).

For example, if $f$ is the density of an absolutely continuous random variable $X$, then $\rho$ could be the Lebesgue measure so that
$$
f=\frac{d\mu}{d\rho}
$$
and
$$
\begin{split}
H_\rho[X] &= - \mathbb{E}_\mu\left[\log \frac{d\mu}{d\rho}\right]\\
&=-\int\log \frac{d\mu}{d\rho}\,d\mu\\
&=-\int \frac{d\mu}{d\rho}\log \frac{d\mu}{d\rho}\,d\rho\\
&=-\int f(x)\log f(x) \, dx.
\end{split}
$$

As you see this reminds a lot the formula
$$
H[X] = -\sum_{x} P[X = x] \log P[X = x],
$$
which could in fact be written in the form $H_\rho[X]$ taking $\rho$ to be the usual counting measure (possibly infinite, but that's fine for this purpose).

Comment: I think you inadvertently dropped a $-$ sign.

Comment: Indeed, thanks.